# Why is LFTP "Removing old file" in mirror?

Tags: mirror, lftp

I'm trying to mirror a website (of which I'm the webmaster) using LFTP, for backup.

I use the LFTP command (actual paths, usernames, and passwords redacted for privacy):

```
mirror -e -p --verbose=1 /public_html /mnt/lobster3raid/<path>/public_html
```

It's working except that LFTP is removing each file from the mirror and then re-transferring it, even if it hasn't changed on the webserver (I get this on every single file every time):

```
Removing old file `<path>/IMG_2003.jpg'
Transferring file `<path>/IMG_2003.jpg'
Removing old file `<path>/IMG_2004.jpg'
Transferring file `<path>/IMG_2004.jpg'
Removing old file `<path>/IMG_2005.jpg'
Transferring file `<path>/IMG_2005.jpg'
```

**How can I run a LFTP mirror that only transfers changed/newer files?**

More background:

The destination mirror is on a Windows share at \\LOBSTER3\raid. I'm doing this on Windows. I had it working OK with Cygwin's LFTP for a while, but lately have been getting permission problems from Windows (apparently Cygwin's LFTP is setting permissions Windows doesn't like).

So I'm now using the LFTP in wsl (Ubuntu). I run this batch file from Windows:

```
wsl -u root -- mkdir /mnt/lobster3raid
wsl -u root -- mount -t drvfs \\\\lobster3\\raid /mnt/lobster3raid
wsl -- lftp -u <username>,<password> <url> -e 'set ssl:check-hostname no; mirror -e -p --verbose=1 /public_html /mnt/lobster3raid/mirrors/1day/public_html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the mirror command without any options, it will transfer all files from the source to the destination, regardless of whether they already exist on the destination or not. This is because the default behavior of mirror is to overwrite existing files on the destination to *exactly* duplicate the source file tree.

The option you're looking for is `--only-newer`. It will re-upload only newer files as stated in the [lftp docs](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html).

So in your case, the batch file should look like this:

```
wsl -u root -- mkdir /mnt/lobster3raid
wsl -u root -- mount -t drvfs \\\\lobster3\\raid /mnt/lobster3raid
wsl -- lftp -u <username>,<password> <url> -e 'set ssl:check-hostname no; mirror -e -p --verbose=1 --only-newer /public_html /mnt/lobster3raid/mirrors/1day/public_html'
```